# Java method code error

Tags: java

I'm trying to Make two calls to a second return method which takes in one parameter ( my value in inches) and prints the value in centimeters but its not working! What did I do wrong?`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     // prompt the user and get the value
     System.out.print("Exactly how many inches are you?  ");
     int uHeight = in.nextInt();

    // converting and outputing the result
    System.out.print("How many inches is your mother? ");
    int mHeight = in.nextInt();
    InchesToCm(mHeight,uHeight);
}  

public static double InchesToCm() {


Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Exactly how many inches are you?  ");
int inHeight = in.nextInt();
double cmHeight = inHeight * 2.54;
System.out.println("He's " + uHeight + " inches or " + mHeight + " cm.");
return
```

Comment: Please be more precise, how is it not working ?

Comment: What is the problem, the exception, the error ? Please edit the question with that information. See [ask]. Well, I dont see a return value in the `InchesToCm` method but no closing bracket either .. so is it the complet method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to pass your mHeight and uHeight, in your method because you call it in your main method like this `InchesToCm(mHeight,uHeight);` so your method should look like this:

```
public static double InchesToCm(int mHeight, int uHeight) {//pass your values in method
```

Second you have to return the result in the end :

```
return cmHeight;//return the result
```

---

**Note**

For the good practice your methods should start with a lowercase letter like @Timothy Truckle said in comment and your class names should start with an upper letter

---

**EDIT**

For the good practice your have to use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Exactly how many inches are you?  ");
    int uHeight = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("He's " + uHeight + " inches or " + inchesToCm(uHeight) + " cm.");
    System.out.print("How many inches is your mother? ");

    int mHeight = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("He's " + mHeight + " inches or " + inchesToCm(mHeight) + " cm.");
    //------------------------------^^-------------------------------^^------------------
    in.close();//close your Scanner
}

//Your function should take inches and return cm
public static double inchesToCm(int height) {
    return height * 2.54;
}
```

Comment: and `InchesToCm` should start with a lowercase letter and a verb: `convertInchesToCm`

Comment: I need to make to Make two calls to a second return method which takes in one parameter ( my value in inches) and prints the value in centimeters

Comment: will changing it to lower case effect it?

Comment: you should point out that `double inchesToCm(int mHeight, int uHeight)` don't make sense. It is a utility function that should get one int and return a double. No scanner needed in there. And off course, the Scanner should be closed in the method but this will bring a lot of problem ;) **EDIT : PERFECT :)**  except that the good practice should close the Sscanner ;)

Comment: @YCF_L, this happen a lot ;) I try to edit as fast as possible in that case, but maybe I should simply quickly add a _editing ..._ to notify that I am adding information. And you are welcome, as always.